# Big Data free text with special characters- search via Python and giving unicode errors

Tags: regex, python-3.x, unicode

Free text with special characters and line spaces between each record and getting impossible to search for key word. I have big text file with 3 columns (each column has seperated by “|”. Seems like each record end with } sign. There is a line gap between each row OR record. My file size is around 100 MB+
My objective is search for multiple key words and surrounding words before and after key word.
With stack overflow help, I am using this code but I am getting Unicode errors. Please help.

1.I want to get only positive result. Or I don’t want see any data if it search won’t matches.

2.Is it possible to see first 4 columns of each findings along with result? Those four columns are fixed length and same for each record.

My file Sample:

```
00010007308000003161|730100039|2007-11-27 09:54:17.000|ACCG| {\rtf1\ansi\deflang1033\ftnbj\uc1
{\fonttbl{\f0 \froman \fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1 \fswiss \fcharset0  Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255 ;\red0\green0\blue0 ;\red255\green0\blue0 
;}
{\stylesheet{\fs20\cf2\cb1 Normal;}{\cs1\cf2\cb1 Default Paragraph Font;}{\s2\cf0\cb1 
;}}
\par\par\par\b 
FOLLOW-According to the United States Census Bureau, the township has a    total area of 15.1 square miles 

(39 km2), of which, 14.6 square miles (38 km2) of it is land and 0.5 square   miles (1.3 km2) of it 

(3.58%) is water. It is drained by the Lehigh River on its western   \clvertalt\cellx4320
\pard\intbl\s0\ql\widctlpar\plain\f1\fs20\lang4105\f1\fs16 3.87 10^6/uL  \cell
\pard\s0\ql\widctlpar\plain\f1\fs20\par\par\b ASSESSMENT:\plain\f1\fs20    Perfect 
As of the census[1] of 2000, there were 4,243 people, 1,671 households, and  1,256 families residing in 

the township. The population cc:\tab Dhar xdfsd,  MD\par\par\par\par\pard\s0\ql\par}

00010007308000003141|730100040|2007-11-27 10:05:09.000|ACCG|   {\rtf1\ansi\deflang1033\ftnbj\uc1
{\fonttbl{\f0 \froman \fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1 \fswiss \fcharset0  Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255 ;\red0\green0\blue0  ;\red255\green0\blue0 
;}
{\stylesheet{\fs20\cf0\cb1 Normal;}{\cs1\cf0\cb1 Default Paragraph Font;} {\s2\cf2\cb1 
;}{\s3\f1\fs22\cf2\cb1\tqc\tx4320\tqr\tx8640 header;}   {\s4\fs20\cf2\cb1\tqc\tx4320\tqr\tx8640 
footer;}}
   \pgwsxn12240\pghsxn15840\marglsxn864\margrsxn864\margtsxn1440\margbsxn864\headery1440\footery864\sbkpage

\pgncont\pgndec
\plain\plain\f1\fs20\pard\par\pard\s3\tqc\tx4320\tqr\tx8640\qc\widctlpar\f0\fs28    \caps 
There were 1,671 households out of which 28.8% had children under the age of  18 living with them, 64.0% 

were married couples living together, 6.9% had a female householder with no  husband present, census 

24.8% were non-families. 19.5% of all households were made up of 
30094 - (770) 761-7260 - FAX (678) 413   -1818\par\lang1024\f0\fs20\par\pard\plain\f1\fs20\par\ql\par\par
}

00010007308000003141|730100036|2007-11-19 12:36:28.000|ACCG| {\rtf1\ansi\deflang1033\ftnbj\uc1
{\fonttbl{\f0 \froman \fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1 \fswiss \fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255 ;\red255\green0\blue0 ;}
{\stylesheet{\fs20\cf0\cb1 Normal;}{\cs1\cf0\cb1 Default Paragraph Font;}}
\paperw12240\paperh15840\margl864\margr864\margt1440\margb864\headery1440\footer y864\deftab720\formshade

\aendnotes\aftnnrlc\pgbrdrhead\pgbrdrfoot
\sectd

\pgwsxn12240\pghsxn15840\marglsxn864\margrsxn864\margtsxn1440\margbsxn864\headery1440\footery864\sbkpage

\pgncont\pgndec
\plain\plain\f1\fs20\lang1033\f1 Home Care Note:  CMN received from Home  Medical 
In the township the population was spread out with 21.4% under the age of  18, 6.5% from 18 to 24, 29.9% 

from 25 to 44, 27.7% from 45 to 64, and 14.6% who were 65 years of age or  older. The median age was 40 

years. For every 100 females there were 101.1 males. For every 100 females  age 18 and over, there were 

98.5 males
on RA on the 18th of Oct.  Cont. O2 at 2L/N/C was ordered.   \plain\f1\fs20\par}

00010007308000003141|730100037|2007-11-15 12:05:02.000|ACCG|Clear Document - Certificate

00010007308000003141|730100038|2007-11-28 08:35:18.000|ACCG {\rtf1\ansi\deflang1033\ftnbj\uc1
{\fonttbl{\f0 \census \fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1 \fswiss \fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255 ;\red0\green0\blue0 ;\red255\green0\blue0 
;}
{\stylesheet{\fs20\cf2\cb1 Normal;}{\cs1\cf2\cb1 Default Paragraph Font;}}
 \paperw12240\paperh15840\margl864\margr864\margt1440\margb864\headery1440\footery864\deftab720\formshade

\aendnotes\aftnnrlc\pgbrdrhead\pgbrdrfoot
called and faxed to Mike.\plain\f1\fs20\par}
```

---

In above file I am searching for 'census' (not case sensitive) and I found matches in 4 places. (2 times in 1st record and 2 times two different records)

Desired output is below...

```
00010007308000003161|730100039|2007-11-27 09:54:17.000|ACCG|United States Census Bureau, the t
00010007308000003161|730100039|2007-11-27 09:54:17.000|ACCG|of the census[1] of 2000
00010007308000003141|730100040|2007-11-27 10:05:09.000|ACCG|husband present, census 24.8% were 
00010007308000003141|730100038|2007-11-28 08:35:18.000|ACCG|fonttbl{\f0 \census \fcharset0 Times
```

---

In above desired example I did choose to display only two words before and after census. That would be great if I have a flexibility to choose more than 2 words.Example 10 words before and 15 words after etc.

Also I am reading this from text file. If you give me a command to read and write back to text file that would be great. Sorry I am new to Python but I love the power of Python.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: But your code shows syntax error during the assignment.

Comment: Use re.findall with this regex https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex.

```
>>> s = r"""4200011|4200002|2006-12-28 10:28:42.000|{\rtf1\ansi 
\deflang1033\ftnbj\uc1
{\fonttbl{\f0 \froman \fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1 \fswiss  
\fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255 ;\red0\green0\blue0 ;}
{\stylesheet{\fs20\cf2\cb1 Normal;}{\cs1\cf2\cb1 Default Paragraph  
Font;}}
\paperw12240\paperh15840\margl864\margr864\margt1152\margb720\head 
ery1152\footery720\deftab720\formshade\aendnotes\aftnnrlc
Called Brian with mike 
\pgbrdrhead
12/27/06 fax 293-4812\plain\f1\fs20\par}

4200011|4200007|2010-11-29 12:49:42.000|{\rtf1\ansi 
\deflang1033\ftnbj\uc1
{\fonttbl{\f0 \froman \fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1 \fswiss  
\fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255 ;\red255\green0\blue0 ;}
{\stylesheet{\fs20\cf0\cb1 Normal;}{\cs1\cf0\cb1 Default Paragraph  
Font;}}
\paperw12240\paperh15840\margl864\margr864\margt1007\margb576\head 
ery1007\footery576\deftab720\formshade\aendnotes\aftnnrlc 
\pgbrdrhead them  numbers and  they pt
minutes\plain\f1\fs20\par}"""
>>> ls = re.findall(r'^(\d+\|\d+)\|(?:(?!\n\n)[\s\S])*?(\S+\s+\S+\s+mike\s+\S+\s+\S+)', s)
>>> print(('|'.join([j for i in ls for j in i])).replace('\n',' '))
4200011|4200002|Brian with mike  \pgbrdrhead 12/27/06
```

Comment: it is working great for 1st record, but it not working for 2nd record. (I added mike to 2nd record ---4200011|4200007|2010-11-29 12:49:42.000|....(that is starting point for 2nd record) and didn't work. Can you help?

Comment: but i didn't find mike in your second record.

Comment: For test purposes, I added mike in 2nd record and tested. But it is not picking up the 2nd record. Please help

Comment: Is it ok if I update with brand new example? It is more real and more data. But 1st and 2nd column length is different in real example. Is it ok?

Comment: I updated sample and desired format as well. I would like to export data from .txt file and import the result back to .txt file. Also can you give me an flexibility to change before and after search words count please??? Thank you so much for your help. You are wonderful!!!

Comment: use this regex https://regex101.com/r/jO6zT2/1 and do the same i said in my answer.

Comment: 00010007308000003161|730100039|2007-11-27 09:54:17.000|ACCG|   I would like to get first 4 words for every record. But I am getting only two. Can you help?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I heading out to office. I will test it out with big file and I let you know. I am so thrilled to test this with huge file.

Comment: @Avinash...I am still picking only first line. But regex is showing all 3 liens. Am I doing something wrong? Please help.

Comment: just add `(?m)` before `^` in your regex.

Comment: Works like a charm!!!! One quick thing...I introduced same key word 2 times in one record but it is picking only first record. Other than that this is super!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
s = r"""4200011|4200002|2006-12-28 10:28:42.000|{\rtf1\ansi

   ^^
```

Try this.Or else you will have to double escape  `\plain\f1\fs20\par`